# Modifying DOM input field through Google Chrome extension not permanent

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Google Chrome extension that, when you highlight a piece of text in an input field, it replaces that highlighted section with a modified version of that text (for example, that text in all uppercase). My primary usecase is on messenger.com, where the input field is in a span tag, but ideally this would be extendable to all sorts of input fields across any website.

My issue is, when I modify this text, as soon as it changes in the input field, it changes right back to the original text.

I have tried various methods, such as emptying the range and re-inserting a node, but the method I am currently using is to modify the innerHTML of the span tag.

manifest.json

```
...
"background": {
     "scripts": ["selection.js", "background.js"],
     "persistent": true
 },

"content_scripts": [
     {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["selection.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true
     }
 ]
```

selection.js

```
function replaceText(modifier) {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        console.log(selection);
        var anchorNode = selection.anchorNode;
        console.log(anchorNode);
        // All the text
        var wholeText = anchorNode.wholeText;
        console.log(wholeText);
        // Highlighted portion
        var selectedText = getSelected();
        // Starting index of replacement section
        var startIndex = selection.anchorOffset;
        // End index of replacement section
        var endIndex = startIndex + selectedText.length;

        // Iterate through and reconstruct the modified string
        var replacementText = modifier(wholeText, startIndex, endIndex);
        console.log("New text: ", replacementText);

        // Replace the string
        if (selection.rangeCount) {
            var active = document.activeElement
            innermost = getInnermost(active);
            console.log(innermost);
            innermost.innerHTML = replacementText
        }
    }
}
```

background.js

```
/*
    When keyboard shortcut detected, fire off message to DOM level content
    script.
*/
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    console.log('entered')
    if (command === 'change') {
        console.log('command detected');
        chrome.tabs.query({active:true, windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT}, 
            function(tab) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, {method: "getSelection"}, 
                function(response){
                    console.log("Got response: ", response.message);
                });
            }
        );
    }
});
```

I expect the highlighted text to change to the new text (and leave everything else unchanged), but this seems to not work despite the many methods I have tried. I have also scoured Stack Overflow and Google - is this possible, and if so, what would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Instead of changing the contents directly via innerHTML you should use document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'your new text') which will replace the current selection.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the suggestion! That poses the same issue - as soon as the text is replaced, it immediately goes back to the original text, and doesn't stay for more than half a second. I'm trying to figure out how to make this permanent - this could also be something specific to messenger.com, but I'd like to figure this out.

Comment: Sounds like the site constantly refreshes the page. Usually it means a bug in their code. You can verify this is the case by opening devtools element inspector on this element and you should see various parts of the element tree flicker periodically on updates. If so, arguably the only solution is to use MutationObserver to
monitor the highest unchanging parent in the tree and re-apply your changes.